# get_pdf api.v8 Odoo. What parameter should I send as "records"

Tags: python, odoo

In the source code of record.py I found

```
@api.v8
    def get_pdf(self, records, report_name, html=None, data=None):
        return Report.get_pdf(self._model, self._cr, self._uid, records.ids,
                          report_name, html=html, data=data, context=self._context)
```

I inherited "record" in my custom module. And I defined a button like this:

```
<record id="report_maker_form" model="ir.ui.view">
                    <field name="name">Impression</field>
                    <field name="model">cust_report</field>
                    <field eval="1" name="priority"/>
                    <field name="arch" type="xml">
                            <form>
                                    <header>
                                            <button string="Envoyer le rapport" type="object" name="send_report_cust"/>
                                    </header>
                                    <sheet>
                                            <group>
                                                    <field name='date'/>
                                            </group>
                                    </sheet>
                            </form>
                    </field>
            </record>
```

The function send_report_cust is defined like this in the inherited report.py.

```
@api.one
    def send_report_cust(self):
            #self.pool.get('report').get_pdf(self, None, "report_vote_document", None, None)
            self.get_pdf(None, "report_vote_document", None, None)
```

So "report_vote_document" is my report_name. I'm just testing to create a report with minimal template. report_vote_document doesn't require any specific records yet, it's just a testing text in template format. So I send as "records" : "None" in parameters for get_pdf.
I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ids'
```

Which is kind of an obvious error since "records" is needed in the get_pdf's body, but I don't know what thoses records are supposed to be. Can anyone tell me what's supposed to be in this "records". What should I send?

EDIT: I'm trying to call get_pdf but something is wrong with the arguments I give to it.

Here is what I did:

```
@api.one
def send_report_cust(self):
    self.get_pdf(self, "my_report_name", "my_report_template", None)
```

I also tried this for the last line.

`self.get_pdf(**my_model_name** , "my_report_name", "my_report_template", None)`

The error I get is :

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/report/models/report.py", line 508, in _get_report_from_name
    idreport = report_obj.search(cr, uid, conditions)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried to get the error with some pdb.set_trace in the source code of the module "report", in "report/models/report.py". Which I tested with my button using "send_report_cust" (let's call it case A) and the basic automatic use of report (case B) with  (which works but won't allow me to have my own button and to do some changes before and after the pdf creation in the same function.)

First in the `@api.v8` of `get_pdf`, which show all went right in this. But this get_pdf call the `@api.v7` of `get_pdf` . In this one, the error occurs on this line:

```
report = self._get_report_from_name(cr, uid, report_name)
```

So here again, I went in _get_report_from_name and used pdb.set_trace().

The whole function goes right and every single variable as exactly the same value in case A than in case B but when _get_report_from_name goes to the line

```
idreport = report_obj.search(cr, uid, conditions)[0]
```

The error occurs on case A but not on case B.

So I did "print report_obj.search(cr, uid, conditions)" which is an empty list for case A (which is what the error describes but I don't get it) and a list with one int for case B. I checked every single variables amongs the 3 functions I tested with pdb.set_trace() and everythings are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Records are database entries in object form. For example `account.invoice`: when you press the print button on an invoice, it will be the record for the report. In your example, `self` will be the record of the model `cust_report` model you pressed the button on.

Every Odoo report is defined for a model. It will need at least one record of the model while printing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so I have to add a one2many from my report.py to the model used in my template? So it's was meaningless to try printing a minimal template without any records, that's why I couldn't make it works. Accepted as an answer.

Comment: Odoo tries to give you the possibility to print documents for business objects like invoices, orders, pickings, and so on. But you can also define a transient model (records are deleted in database by a job) and a report for that. What you're doing with that model and report, depends on your wishes. For example: a report for all open invoices for a specific period of  time. You just need a transient model with start and end date fields to do that. Getting the data for printing can be done in the report.

Comment: So if I want to use my model in which I redefine get_pdf how can I do so? When I try to send self as record I get an IndexError, I guess I have to add some precision after "self" but I don't know which ones. When I used only xml to call a report (so setting <record></record> and the template without redefining get_pdf it worked but here it won't.)

EDIT: here is what appears before the IndexError in the logs:
idreport = report_obj.search(cr, uid, conditions)[0]

Comment: What about the argument "report_name", should it be the template id? (As it is here.)

Comment: Well I give my template for the third argument (html="template_name")

Comment: You don't need to override get_pdf for a new report. You need your model (let's call it `my.model`). For `my.model` just create a tree view and a menuitem. Now create a report on that model, like in [Odoo 9](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/sale/sale_report.xml). Now you need the QWeb report like in [Odoo 9](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/sale/views/report_saleorder.xml). For cool stuff you will need to create a parser class like in [Odoo 9](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/point_of_sale/report/pos_invoice.py). I hope that will help.

Comment: Yes I think I've found an other solution based on what you gave me. I'll try that, but what I was really trying to do is defining an other button than "print" in the form like my code above is doing, in which I'll call the get_pdf. I made an error in the lasts comments, I'm not trying to override get_pdf but just to call it from my own function (because I want to do some modifications when I press the same button.). My bad and I apologise. So I call it like this : get_pdf(self, "my_name_report", "report_vote_document", None) Which trigger the error described in previous comments.

Comment: I edited to explain research I made. Do I need to cancel that Edit and create a new topic? Because I don't want to spam the forum but maybe it would be better?

Comment: Your questions are way to much for SO ;-) And i have not much time to answer such questions, sorry.